# Certificates in AWS IoT Core are not accessible / An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, aws-iot

I have registered a CA certificate in AWS IoT Core. Additionally I have registered (via JITP) device certificates that are signed with the CA certificate.

Up until four hours ago my devices where able to connect to AWS IoT. Currently only devices using AWS issued certificates are able to connect.

When reading details (AWS IoT > Secure > Certificates > cert_id) for my own registered certificates AWS console responds:
***An unexpected error has occurred.
Cannot read public key. OID is not RSA.***
Also the console won't respond anymore without browser refresh.

I also tried to register a certificate again. That doesn't work because AWS knows the certificate is already registered.

Any pointers what could be wrong?

I only have basic support plan from AWS so I didn't find a way to ask AWS directly.

Ilkka

Answer (score 0):

This is an error when using the new console experience, and has been escalated to be researched and resolved. This has no impact on any use of the ECC certificates. I created and registered an ECC certificate using the CLI and mosquitto on 22-Jan-2022 and all was working then. If you do have connectivity problems, enable logging from the AWS IoT Console->Settings, and then review the logs in CloudWatch Logs.

In the meantime, you can turn off the new console experience from the AWS IoT Console at the bottom of the left menu pane, under the Documentation link.